# Clearing or resetting a knockout validation validatedObservable?

Tags: knockout-validation

I have a view model as such:

```js
var prop1 = ko.observable().extend{ required: true },
    prop2 = ko.observable().extend{ required: true };

var validation = ko.validatedObservable([prop1, prop2]);

function resetFields() {
    prop1(undefined);
    prop2(undefined);
}

var vm = {
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,
    validation: validation,
    reset: resetFields
};
```

The properties prop1 and prop2 are being validated correctly via the validatedObservable, however when I execute resetFields, these properties then have errors on them since they've been modified and are required.

Is there a way to reset the validated observable, as if it had not been changed?

**Update:** I was sourcing knockout.validation from NuGet, and using v1.0.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot reset on the `validatedObservable` level but you can call `clearError` on the individual properties:

```js
vm.reset();
console.log(vm.validation.isValid()); // output: false
prop1.clearError();
prop2.clearError();
console.log(vm.validation.isValid()); // output: true
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9twPU/)

Note: **It only works with a "recent" version** of the validation plugin so the `clearError` **is not included** in the CDNJS and Nuget version of plugin. My JSFiddle demo uses the latest version ([9fd5a4d2da](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/commit/9fd5a4d2dac4c55c420eda858fa23a7f7531eccc)) from GitHub.

Answer (score 12):

When using a validated observable, I found out that you can call `validatedObservable.errors.showAllMessages(false)` after you have cleared the observable, which is behaving the way I was expecting in my application.

Comment: This solution could work but not in all cases: the `showAllMessages(false)` only sets the `isModied` observables to false which results in the error messages removed however **it does not clear the validation result**. So the `isValid()` will remain `false`: `vm.reset();
console.log(vm.validation.isValid()); //output: false
vm.validation.errors.showAllMessages(false)
console.log(vm.validation.isValid()); //output: false`  http://jsfiddle.net/CjsCS/